# Sort entity list based on entity property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I am using entity framework and generating a simple list of returned objects such as

```
RetVal.Add(new Leaderboard() { 
           Category = CategoryID, 
           User = u.FirstName, 
           Score = GetCategoryScoreForUser(u.Username,(int)CategoryID).ToString() });
```

`RetVal` is a List of Leaderboard.

Each Leaderboard object has a property named Score, what i want to do is to re-order RetVal so that it now contains the list but in descending order based on Score.

I tried the following:

```
 RetVal.Sort(x => x.Score);
```

and

```
 RetVal.OrderBy(x=>x.Score);
```

but nothing changes.

can someone please help me?

Comment: how do you know **nothing changes**?

Comment: because i get the same order in RetVal with or without the code i tried. why the order of entities not changes?

Comment: It **can't** change the original list because it **does not** modify it. You have create a new list from the query or use the query directly such as by looping through it. However the use of `Sort` should work, the use of `OrderBy` won't.

Comment: You should show the code you tried to know that nothing changes.

Comment: ok, so i tried the following List<Leaderboard> SortedList = RetVal.OrderBy(x=>x.Score).ToList(); but no luck

Comment: What's the data type of `Score`?

Comment: got it, was string, so changed it to int and it works, any ideas how i could reverse the list (like 100, 90, 80) etc

Comment: @user1144596: Do you mean `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store the score as numeric string, try this:

```
RetVal.OrderByDescending(x=>int.Parse(x.Score));
```

If you modified it to `int`, try this:

```
RetVal.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list:

```
var newList = RetVal.OrderBy(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

When you're iterating over the list you don't have to do that and can just use

```
foreach(var leaderboard in RetVal.OrderBy(x => x.Score)) {
    Console.WriteLine(leaderboard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your want to edit original array,like this:

```
RetVal=RetVal.Sort(x => x.Score);
```

or

```
RetVal=RetVal.OrderBy(x=>x.Score);
```